# How to retrieve all the img id in a Webdriver Selenium Java

Tags: selenium

In a Browser I have couple of `img` `id`'s which shall dynamically change in every different selection of the release date.

Can you please guide me with a selenium web driver code which shall click the checkbox image, even if the image `id` changes over every different selection of the release date.

**How to retrieve all the `img` `id`'s in a web browser?**

```
<img id="R1410ENDec14001001" class="child-img" src="../dyn/assets/checkbox_unchecked.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with class or other properties if the id is dynamic like

```
//img[@class='child-img'] or
//img[contains(@src,'checkbox_unchecked.png')]
```

To retrieve all the image's which has id you can go with the following xpath

```
//img[@id]
```

Use findElements By xpath using the above one, and iterate over and get the id atribute of each element